# Angular: Console.log(11) is printed first then console.log(1). why?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple submit method, where Console.log(11) is printed first then console.log(1). I need why it is behaving in that way.

```
submit(value) {

    this.secServise.getUserById(this.currentUser.mgId).subscribe( uAddrs => {
      this.tempUser = uAddrs;
      console.log(1);
    });

    if (value[this.keyPwd] !== value[this.keyCPwd]) {
      this.messageService.add({
         severity: 'error',
         summary: 'Password and Confirm Password should match',
         detail: '' 
      });
    } else {
      console.log(11);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the `subscription` is an asynchronous process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Angular but rather with the way Javascript works. Basically your code is not synchronous like you would expect because your `getUserById` call is most likely asynchronous.

This means Javascript will not wait until the `getUserById` callback function is called. Instead it will just continue with the next line of code which apparently in this case is the `console.log(11)` line since the if statements evaluates as false.

Comment: how do i overcome that?

Comment: Looking at the code you shared you could move all code into the function called by the subscriber.